# AIR for desktop and TouchEvents

Tags: actionscript-3, air, touch, desktop

Building a kiosk application that only requires button press and button drag(scroller) detection.

I DON'T need multitouch, or gesture recognition.

Will I still need to substitute any MouseEvents for TouchEvents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use only `MouseEvent` for a desktop application.